# Days tracker in excel, until closure date or today?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, spreadsheet, date-difference

I have a spreadsheet with these 3 columns

1. starting date (has to have a value)
2. closing date (can have a value or be blank)
3. days passed (actual days, weekends and such included)

I would like to know which formula i can use to have this result:

If (2) is blank, then (3) has to show the date difference between today and (1), obviously updating every day

If (2) has a valid value,then (3) should be the date differenze betweeen (2) and (1)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

If A2 has starting date, and B2 has closing date, place this in C2:

```
=IF(ISBLANK( B2),TODAY()-A2,B2-A2)
```